# How to create a string with a char array in C?

Tags: c, string, file, pointers

I am an Android and Java developer and I am not much familiar with C language. As well as you know there is not a String type in C. All I want is getting chars, putting them into an char array and writing these characters as a string. How can I take the whole string which is a array of characters and put it into a variable? This is my code but it does not work properly. The log which I get is:

```
I/        ( 2234): *********PROPERTY = 180000€¾Ü    €¾Ü €¾
```

It should have been 180000.

```
int c;
char output[1000];
int count = 0;
char *property;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("/cache/lifetime.txt", "r");
LOGI("****************FILE OPEN*************");
if (file) {
    LOGI("*****************FILE OPENED************");
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        output[count] = c;
        ++count;
        LOGI("******C = %c", c);
    }
    property = output;
    LOGI("*********PROPERTY = %s", property);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is a `'\0'`. All strings in C are just a sequence of characters ending with a `'\0'`.

So, once your loop

```
while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
```

is done, you can add the statement

```
output[count] = '\0'
```

---

Below modifications are needed if you intend to return the `property` variable outside the local function and if `output` is a variable local to the function.

In the above below line will need modification

```
property = output;
```

You should allocate memory for property using [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and then use [strcpy](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcpy/) to copy the string in output to property or do a [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) as suggested by Joachim in the comment.

Using strdup, the statement will be like below

```
property = strdup(output);
```

Comment: Actually `property = output;` is fine, though it does not copy any data, just creates a pointer reference to the data stored in output.

Comment: Depending on use, the `property` pointer might not need to be allocated. And it's easier to do it in one step with the `strdup` function.

Comment: Yes. it is, for this standalone code snippet. My guess was that he was assigning so he could return property out of this function. Anyways, have edited my answer. Hope it is fine.

Comment: Actually I wanna use the string in another function. I wannna write  property_set("persist.sys.lifetime", property); Should I use malloc? How can I do it?

Comment: You can use strdup instead of malloc. I have edited my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Determine whether the number of characters is known at compile time or runtime, then allocate the array either statically or dynamically:

```
char some_property [N+1]; // statically allocate room for N characters + 1 null termination

// or alternatively, dynamic memory allocation:
char* property = malloc (count + 1);
```

Then copy the data into the new variable:

```
memcpy(some_string, output, count); 

some_string[count] = '\0'; // null terminate

...
free(property); // clean up, if you used dynamic memory (and only then)
```

Or simply use the "output" variable already in place, by adding a null termination at the end of the input.